# InstantiationException for newInstance()

Tags: java, reflection

Following works fine when the `className` is `"java.awt.Rectangle"` and `"java.lang.String"` etc. But it fails for `"java.lang.Integer"`, `"java.lang.Double"` giving `java.lang.InstantiationException` for `classDefinition.newInstance()`.

```
Class classs = Class.forName(className);
Object object = classs.newInstance();
```

Is this a problem with the Wrapper classes or another?

**Editted : Way to do this - credits should go to Jigar.**

```
Class       integerDefinition   = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
Constructor intArgsConstructor  = integerDefinition.getConstructor(new Class[] {int.class});
Object[]    intArgs             = new Object[] { new Integer(12) };
Object      object              = intArgsConstructor.newInstance(intArgs);
```

Comment: It's clearly written in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) (*Throws* section: "or if the class has no nullary constructor;")

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) doesn't have no-arg(default) constructor, `class.newInstance()` will invoke default constructor internally

Comment: Thanks Jigar, got your point. now I'm working on constructor.neWInstance()

Comment: You are welcome, [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ObjectReflectioninvokeconstructorwithparameters.htm) will help you in that part

Comment: Thanks for the reference Jigar. I updated the question providing an answer with the help of it.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense. However, what is wrong with something like [this](https://ideone.com/JS4Ze0) where the class on which `newInstance` is invoked has only one no-arg constructor?

Answer (score 12):

[Class.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) can only invoke the zero-argument constructor and [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) doesn't have ZERO argument constructor.

Comment: Thanks thinksteep, got your point too. Now I'm working on constructor.neWInstance()