# How can I initialize a generic variable in Java?

Tags: java, generics, initialization

I am trying to write a method in which I need to create a temp variable, sum, of generic type T. However, I'm getting the error "The local variable sum may not have been initialized". How can I initialize a generic variable? I can't set it to 0 or 0.0, and I can't find information anywhere on how to deal with this. Here is the portion of code that I'm working with:

```
public Matrix<T,A> multiply(Matrix<T,A> right) throws MatrixException
{
    Matrix<T,A> temp = new Matrix<T,A>(arithmetics, rowSize, columnSize);

    T sum, product;

    if (rowSize != right.columnSize)
        throw new MatrixException("Row size of first matrix must match column size " 
                + "of second matrix to multiply");

    setup(temp,rowSize,columnSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < right.columnSize; j++) {
            product = (arithmetics.multiply(matrix[i][j] , right.matrix[j][i]));
            sum = arithmetics.add(product, sum);
            temp.matrix[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I'm not sure if this will help clarify, but here is my interface Arithmetics:

```
public interface Arithmetics<T> {

public T zero();
public T add( T a, T b );
public T subtract( T a, T b);
public T multiply (T a, T b);
public T parseString( String str );
public String toString( T a );

}
```

And here is one of my classes, DoubleArithmetics, just to show how I'm implementing the interface:

```
public class DoubleArithmetics implements Arithmetics<Double> {

protected Double value;

public Double zero() 
{

    return new Double(0);
}

public Double add( Double a, Double b ) 
{

    return new Double(a.doubleValue()+b.doubleValue());
}

public Double subtract (Double a, Double b)
{
    return new Double(a.doubleValue()-b.doubleValue());
}

public Double multiply (Double a, Double b)
{
    return new Double(a.doubleValue()*b.doubleValue());
}

public Double parseString( String str )
{
    return Double.parseDouble(str);
}

public String toString( Double a )
{
    return a.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try initializing it to null?

Comment: If the null thing above doesn't work for you, how about creating a static method: `T sum = Arithmetics.initialize();`.  You can return a Double from that method.

Comment: @WandMaker, I was able to initialize it to null. I don't know how I overlooked that! Thank you.

Comment: cool, i posted it as answer.   Other answer by Brian seems more elegant.

Comment: Actually, @WandMaker, when I initialize to null, a NullPointerException is thrown. It seems that when the add() method is called, and sum is set to null, the exception is thrown. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: You have to create an instance of type T first.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `zero` method that you already have on your interface to initialize `sum`:

```
T sum = arithmetics.zero();
```

For the non-zero initialization, you could also add methods that take `long` and `double` values and return the `T` for them:

```
public interface Arithmetics<T> {

    public T zero();
    public T create(long l);
    public T create(double d);
    public T add( T a, T b );
    public T subtract( T a, T b);
    public T multiply (T a, T b);
    public T parseString( String str );
    public String toString( T a );
}
```

And then implement them:

```
public Double create(long l) {
    return new Double(l);
}

public Double create(double d) {
    return new Double(d);
}
```

And finally, to use them:

```
T one = arithmetics.create(1);
```

Comment: By using methods in that way (namely, returning a specific type instead of the generic type), you are defeating the whole purpose of the generic container. The create() method should return type T. Implementations of Arithmetics<T> should likewise have a create() that returns type T.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 What are you talking about? My methods clearly return `T`, both of them are `public T create`.

Comment: The interface's create() method returns T. The implementation's method should also return T. In your code, your implementation's create() methods return Double.

Comment: Because the implementation has `implements Arithmetic<Double>` in his example, so I was showing an example implementation in line with his.

Answer (score 3):

Instantiating generics in Java is a bit tricky due to type erasure.

My approach is to pass into your generic class' constructor two items: (1) a java.lang.reflect.Constructor specific to type T; and (2) an Object[] array holding a default value specific to type T.

When you later want to instantiate and initialize a type T, you need to call Constructor.newInstance(Object[]). In the code below, the MyGenericClass class stands in for your generic class (looks like it's called Matrix from your original post).

I got the solution from [InstantiationException for newInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822621/instantiationexception-for-newinstance) and [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    Constructor _constructorForT;
    Object[] _initialValueForT;

    public MyGenericClass(Constructor constructorForT, 
                          Object[] initialValueForT)
    {
        _constructorForT = constructorForT;
        _initialValueForT = initialValueForT;
    }

    public void doSomething() 
    {
        T sum = initializeT(_constructorForT, _initialValueForT);

        System.out.printf("d = %f\n", sum);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T initializeT(Constructor constructor, Object[] args)
    {
        T result = null;

        try
        {
            result = (T) constructor.newInstance(args);
        }
        catch (java.lang.InstantiationException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (java.lang.IllegalAccessException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ex)
        {
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        Constructor constructor = 
            Double.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{double.class});

        Object[] initialValue = new Object[] { new Double(42.0) };

        MyGenericClass<Double> myGenericClass = 
            new MyGenericClass<Double>(constructor, initialValue);

        myGenericClass.doSomething();

    }
}
```